# Rewrite Rule for Manipulating Query parameter - middle value in long Query Value

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Trying to achieve

Source -

```
https://rrr.rrr.com/us/Product-Family/Products/c/Products/layout?layoutType=false&page=0&grid=true&q=:relevance:DriveType:Flash:ProductFamily:Prd 1
```

To

```
 https://rrr.rrr.com/us/Product-Family/Products/c/Products/layout?layoutType=false&page=0&grid=true&q=:relevance:DriveType:Flash SSD:ProductFamily:Prd 1
```

trying to find and replace `DriveType:Flash` to `DriveType:Flash SSD` anywhere in Query String

Problem is that `DriveType:Flash SSD` can appear anywhere in the Query String

Comment: Literally _anywhere_ in the query string? Or anywhere within the `q` parameter value of the query string (as in your example)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)DriveType:Flash:(.*)$
RewriteRule ^us/Product-Family/Products/c/Products/layout$ /$0?%1DriveType:Flash SSD:%2 [R=301,L]
```

This only matches the URL specified and externally redirects to the new URL. This could perhaps be made more efficient by restricting the pattern that will match before and after the required string. At the moment `.*` matches *anything* (and nothing).

In the `RewriteRule` substitution: `$0` is the entire string/URL matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern and `%1` and `%2` are the corresponding sub patterns in `RewriteCond` matched before and after the required string to replace.

Note that I've included the `:` at the end of the pattern to avoid a rewrite loop. If the pattern does not always end with a `:` then this will need to be changed.